# Global.asax.cs name 'RouteConfig' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#

there are three files in my solution which I think I referencing but I am stuck with these 3 errors

Global.asax.cs name 'RouteConfig' does not exist in the current context

What am I missing ? thanks:)

[image]

[image]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.SessionState;
using System.Web.Http;


namespace PingYourPackage.API.WebHost
{
    public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {

        protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var config = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;


            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(config);
            WebAPIConfig.Configure(config);
            AutofacWebAPI.Initialize(config);
        }

***************
```

here is the class autofac

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Http;
using Autofac;
using Autofac.Integration.WebApi;
using System.Reflection;


namespace PingYourPackage.Config
{
    public class AutofacWebAPI
    {
        public static void Initialize(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            Initialize(config,
                RegisterServices(new ContainerBuilder()));
        }

        public static void Initialize (
            HttpConfiguration config, IContainer container)
        {
            config.DependencyResolver =
                new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
        }

        private static IContainer RegisterServices(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

            // registeration goes here

            return builder.Build();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: sounds like you have a `namespace` issue also where in the screen shot is the `Global.asax.cs file can you show that file and it's full class signature including the namespace part..?

Comment: Does those classes exist in those files? What namespace? What's the build action?

Comment: there are other methods after application_start but no errors.

Comment: yes there are methods in those classes

Comment: Look at the namespaces and you will see your problem.

Comment: i tried using PingYourPackage.Config; but no luck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you generate a new project, these `*Config` classes (e.g. `RouteConfig`) are put in `App_Code` by default.

It looks like you moved the `*Config` classes out from the `App_Code` directory, into a `Config` directory. Everything in `App_Code` is automatically referenced by other code in your project.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex526337(v=vs.140).aspx

> Code in the `App_Code` folder is referenced automatically in your application.

It is okay that you moved them, they can live anywhere. Now, you just need to reference them manually inside your `Global.asax.cs` file.

```
using PingYourPackage.Config;
```

(assuming `PingYourPackage` is the name of your project/root namespace)

Comment: thanks for the reply... its a reference I need but using PingYourPackage.Config; doesn't work.  I get another error: he type or namespace name 'Config' does not exist in the namespace 'PingYourPackage.API' (are you missing an assembly reference?)... Yes PingYourPackage is the name of my project/namespace.  I can't get access to the config folder.. i need it seperated for another part of the solution.  using PingYourPackage.API.Config; stops the three errors but throws up one error of the same - missing reference

Comment: @Aindriu looking at your screenshots, it looks like you have many projects in one solution. this looks like you are trying to do a little too much modularized too early. Why was a single project in your solution not good enough to start and learn? If you do need multiple projects, you will need to add a reference to your `PingYourPackage.API` project (the one with the configs) to your `PingYourPackage.API.WebHost` project (the one with the Global). Than the `using` statement will work.

Comment: Your answer got me on the right track. Turns out my project somehow dumped my RouteConfig file altogether. I just copied it over from another project, cleaned and rebuilt the project, and then everything worked again.

Answer (score 4):

This can also be resolved by adding RouteConfig.cs class in your App_Start folder 
You may be missing the cs file there

Answer (score 2):

I added `using System.Web.Routing;` to my code, and worked for me!